Probability involving unequal sample space
Roll a six sided die labelled $1-6$, and if the roll yields a $6$, then you roll a five sided die labelled $1-5$ for the second roll, otherwise you reroll the six sided die. Find the probability of obtaining a $5$ on the second roll assuming you rolled an even number on the first.
Let $A$ denote the event of a $5$ on roll the second roll, $B$ be the event of an even roll on the first, so we have to compute $P(A|B)$.
My approach was to also define $C$ to be the event of obtaining a $6$ on the first to break that case up.
We have $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)P^{-1}(B)$ and I tried to expand $B$ into $P(B)=P(B\cap C)+P(B\cap\overline{C})=P(B| C)P(C)+P(B|\overline{C})P(\overline{C})$ however not all pair of rolls are equally likely in our sample space as getting a six on the second die will not be possible if your first roll was a six, so I don't believe I can conclude that $P(C)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $P(\overline{C})=\frac{5}{6}$.
Any help?

There are (effectively) two paths to getting a $5$ on the second toss.  Compute the probability of both and add.    Should say:  the problem statement is not clear.  I don't know if you are asking for the conditional probability or the straight probability.  In your notation, are you asking for $P(A,|,B)$ or $P(A\cap B)$?

The conditional probability $P(A|B)$

Ok.  I suggest editing your post to make that clear.

In any case, since $P(B)$ is easy to compute, you just need to compute $P(A\cap B)$.

$P(B)$ isn’t $\frac{1}{2}$ right? How do you take the second roll into account?

$P(B)=\frac 12$.  $B$ has nothing to do with the second roll.

Pardon me for this confusion. But I used to always think of any probability as $\frac{|A|}{|S|}$ where $|A|$ is the set cardinality of outcomes for event $A$. So for example rolling two fair six sided die one after another, I think of the event of getting a $1$ on the first roll as looking at all $36$ outcomes and seeing $6$ of them with a $1$ as the first roll, so the probability is $\frac{6}{36}=\frac{1}{6}$, and not as one dice having a $1$ on one of its six faces and thus we have $\frac{1}{6}$. What's the justification of ignoring the second roll entirely like you did here?

I don't see any need for a chat.  the probability of throwing an even number with a fair six sided die is $\frac 12$.  That is what your event $B$ is.  The fact that observing the event $B$, or at least cases of it, might cause someone to do or not do something else has nothing to do with its probability.

Since you are given that the first roll was even:

The probability of a 6 on the first roll is $~1/3.$ 
If this occurs, then the probability of a 5 on the 2nd roll is $~1/5.$

The probability of not rolling a 6 on the first roll is $~2/3.$ 
If this occurs, then the probability of a 5 on the 2nd roll is $~1/6.$


So, the desired computation is
$$\left[ ~\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{5} ~\right] + \left[ ~\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{6} ~\right].$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
There are two distinct ways of concluding that the probability of a 6 on the first roll is $~1/3.~$
One way is to use your intuition, reasoning that you are choosing some random element from $~\{2,4,6\},~$ which is the set of even numbers.
The more formal approach, which is based on conditional probability is to
let

$A~$ denote the event of rolling a $~6.$

$B~$ denote the event of rolling an even number.


Then,
$$p(A|B) = \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)} = \frac{1/6}{3/6}.$$

@wolfgangmozart12 I am having trouble understanding your comment.  Since the first roll is given to be even, the probability of a 6 on the first roll is $~1/3.~$ If that happens, then the probability of a 5 on the 2nd roll is $~1/5.~$ This is consistent with my analysis and my computation.  Assuming that I have made an analytical error somewhere, please explain more clearly what my error is.

I meant in your addendum, you say P(A|B)=1/3 while in the first part your result is 8/45

@wolfgangmozart12 I am using events $~A~$ and $~B~$ differently from the original poster.  Perhaps the following explanation will help.  Let $~M~$ denote the event that the first roll is a 6. Let $~N~$ denote the event that the first roll is even.  Let $~Q~$ denote the event that the 2nd roll is a 5.  In effect, throughout my answer, I have consistently computed $~p(M|N) = 1/3.~$ Further, by the analysis at the start of my answer, I have computed $~p(Q|N) = 8/45.~$ In your mind, does this resolve the issue of whether my answer contains an analytical mistake?

Yes that makes complete sense, thanks for clarification, I just wanted to say it would be clearer if you used events to compute the final result 8/45 not just the probability of rolling a six out of the 3 even numbers, since OP appears to be still confused judging by his comments.
